# On rotate of sprite in cocos2-x with getBoundingBox() method

Tags: cocos2d-x-3.0

after rotating sprites, when we check sprite rectangular area by using getBoundingBox() method, its give same as before rotation.

with rotation of sprite, i changed its height and width, but still getBoundingBox() does not give as sprite is visible after rotation.

Answer (score 0):

getBoundingBox is calculated with contentSize and Scale factor.
You can manually set bounding box with getBoundingBox().setRect() function.

Or add custom variables to call to handle rotated data.

If you implementing the collision, there is great article on [gamedev](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/2d-rotated-rectangle-collision-r2604).